# How to assign a subnet_id to an EC2 module from the main file in Terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

Certainly! Here's a question you can post on Stack Overflow for your scenario:

---

**Title:** How to assign a subnet_id to an EC2 module from the main file in Terraform?

**Question:**
I'm working on a Terraform project, and I have an EC2 module that I want to deploy with various configurations, including the subnet it should be launched in. I'd like to define the subnet_id in the main Terraform file to make the configuration more flexible.

Here's a simplified structure of what I have:

```
main.tf
└── modules
    ├── ec2
    │   ├── ec2.tf
    └── network
        ├── network.tf
```

I want to assign the `subnet_id` for the EC2 instance from the `main.tf` file where I'm using the EC2 module. How can I achieve this in Terraform?

Here's an example of how I'm using the module in my `main.tf`:

```
module "my_ec2" {
  source = "./modules/ec2"
  # How do I set the subnet_id here?
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to pass the `subnet_id` from the `main.tf` to the `ec2.tf` within the module. Thank you!